# Poor performance with Metal in SceneKit

Tags: macos, scenekit, metal

I've been playing around with Metal and SceneKit on OS X and I'm seeing very poor performance when using meshes with lightmaps.

I created a sample project here:
https://github.com/OskarGroth/SlowMetal

It is based on the cornell box scene from Apple's WWDC 2014 project.

This sample highlights my performance issues with Metal in SceneKit. When running with OpenGL, the app maintains 50-60 FPS on my Macbook 13" with Intel Iris 6100. When switching to Metal, the statistics report 40-50 FPS, but the experienced FPS is more like 5-10.

The issue is most obvious when zooming in so that you are inside the box, and maximizing the window.

Is this a bug/issue with Metal or am I missing something here?

Comment: I also found performance problems with Metal shaders in SpriteKit, just an FYI: http://www.modejong.com/blog/post20_spritekit_repeat_shader